# javascript textbox accepting only 1/4 numbers

Tags: javascript, textbox, numbers, acceptance

I need to write a code in javascript to accept numbers in a **textbox** in a certain interval (**that part is done**, between 0 and 16) and now I need it to accept numbers such as 1.5, 1.75, 9.75, 0, 3.25, etc. All numbers with their quarts. All other numbers should be rejected.

Accepted = textbox background is green.
Rejected = textbox background is red.

```js
 <script type="text/javascript">
       function readNumbersAndReturnsArray() { //to fix
        var tabNombre = new Array()

        
        for (var i = 0; i < 7; i++){
          var strNombre = document.getElementById('tbNbHrs' + i).value

          if (isAnEmptyString(strNombre) || !containsNumbersOnly(strNombre)) 
          {
            var strMiseEnForme = 'sNotNumber'
          }
          else if (!estDansIntervalle(strNombre,'0','16'))
          {
            var strMiseEnForme = 'sOutOfLimit'
          }
          else if(-----------) //this is the part where I should accept numbers and their quarts only (0, 0.25, 0.5, 0.75, 1, 1.25, etc.)
          {
            var strMiseEnForme = 'sNotQuart'
          }
          else
          {
            var strMiseEnForme = 'sValid'
            strNombre = Number(strNombre)
            tabNombre.push(strNombre)
          }
          document.getElementById('tbNbHrs' + i).className = strMiseEnForme
        }
      
      return tabNombre
```

Note: All other functions are already working and coded in a js library.

Comment: You made a snippet. Add the HTML and the CSS to it please

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution is to use the **modulus operator**. The modulus operator returns the *remainder* of a division operation.

The modulus operator is represented as a **%** in javascript and many other languages.

For example:

- 5 % 2    = 1
- 15 % 4   = 3
- 253 % 13 = 6
- 1.25 % 0.25 = 0

All the numbers you list as "valid" (1, 1.25, 3.75 etc.) are divisible by 0.25. Simply use the modulus operator and see if you get a remainder of 0. If so then the number is divisible by 0.25 and is valid.

Your if statement should be:

```
if(strNombre % 0.25 == 0){
    // VALID: Number is 1.75, 2, 2.25 etc.
}else{
    // INVALID
}
```

Comment: Thanks! Finally that's what I've done and I thought it wasn't good because of a different mistake I've done before..

:)

Comment: @madpitbull Sure thing! If it helped you solve your issue consider marking the answer as accepted. Good luck with the rest of it :D